# Incorrect calculation in C#

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy, calculation

Why `(0.406 * 10000.0)` returns `4060.0000000000005` instead of `4060.0` in C#

I have written a function which checks no. of decimals in a double value and below is the code I am using. The problem described in the above sentence occurs when value of `d is 0.406` and values of `n is 4` and the function returns `true` instead of `false`

I am open to using alternate solution.

```
public static bool HasMoreThanNDecimals(double d, int n)
{
    return !(d * (double)Math.Pow(10, n) % 1 == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use decimal type instead of double for more precision to get the desired result.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/decimal-vs-double-difference?forum=csharpgeneral